# Python issue with class local scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, scope

The following python code will set a secret key if the user does not provide one

**Code with NameError:**

```
import secrets
import string
import os

class Config:
    secret = os.environ.get('SECRET')
    if not secret:
        alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        secret = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(256))
```

However, if secret is not set, this will result in a `NameError: name 'alphabet' is not defined`. What confuses me most is that the following variations of `Config` work properly:

**Config without join (no error):**

```
class Config:
    secret = os.environ.get('SECRET')
    if not secret:
        alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        secret = alphabet * 10   # just repeat the alphabet 10 times as the password
```

**Config with `alphabet` in main scope (no error)**

```
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

class Config:
    secret = os.environ.get('SECRET')
    if not secret:
        secret = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(256))
```

**Troubleshooting I've tried**

1. Verify all indentation is correct (each block uses 4 spaces)
2. Test on python 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9 (all show identical results)
3. Test code in Python REPL to check for errors (identical results again)
4. Test simpler variations (remove `os`, `string`, etc.)

**Question**

What is causing the `NameError`? Am I misunderstanding how the class scope behaves or is this a bug in python?

Comment: Essentially, the generator expression you use creates its own scope, it literally creates a function which gets called. Like any function in a class block, the function local scope does not have access to the class block scope. In a nutshell, class blocks are not enclosing scopes, but you are trying to rely on an enclosing scope in your generator expression